# PIL - Not a valid numbers of quantization tables. Should be between 2 and 4

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

My PIL library works fine for a while, but now i get this exception everywhere, how to fix this?

```
f = "/media/bighdd/1.jpg"
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(f)
im.thumbnail('50x50')
im.save('/media/bighdd/2.jpg')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1437, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 471, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, fp, [("jpeg", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 494, in _save
    for e, b, o, a in tile:
ValueError: Not a valid numbers of quantization tables. Should be between 2 and 4.
```

Comment: You should go to line 494 in ImageFile.py and determine where the error is being thrown by adding your own logging; or something. This could be a fun exercise in debugging a major package! ...or you could just re-download the binaries and install again.

Answer (score 2):

check that you import Image in this way:

```
from PIL import Image
```

I had the same error when in my code was

```
import Image
```

and this tiny change make things roll

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a `virtualenv`? In my case, the error was in the `sorl` library, in the `get_thumbnail` method call. Therefor, I was not supposed to change code in the library, which is a bad practice. I figured out that `sorl` was using the `PIL` library installed in my web hosting provider's system, and not the one in my virtualenv. So, I added my virtualenv's site-packages folder (normally with the form `"/home/user/.virtualenvs/virtualenv-name/lib/python2.7/site-packages"`) to the beginning of the `sys.path`, and the problem was solved, since the version of `PIL` and `sorl` installed in the virtualenv are newer than the ones installed in the system, and had this problem solved. I hope this can be useful!

Comment: BTW, in my virtualenv I have installed: `sorl-thumbnail==11.12`, `PIL==1.1.7` and `Pillow==2.1.0`.